# catalogrule_product_price and catalogrule_product are empty

Tags: sql, indexing, catalog-price-rules, ce-1.9.2.2

I am trying to apply catalog rule for 27% from 2 customer group but it's not applied after indexing and cleaning cache.

So i debug the issue and found that **catalogrule_product_price** and **catalogrule_product** are empty. I am using Magento ver. 1.9.2.2

Following query has been generate while apply ruel

```
INSERT INTO `catalogrule_product_price` SELECT NULL AS `rule_product_price_id`, `dates`.`rule_date`, `t`.`customer_group_id`, `t`.`product_id`, MIN(rule_price) AS `rule_price`, 1 AS `website_id`, `t`.`latest_start_date`, `t`.`earliest_end_date` FROM (SELECT `cppt`.`customer_group_id`, `cppt`.`product_id`, CASE WHEN IFNULL((@group_id), 'N/A') != cppt.grouped_id THEN @price := CASE `cppt`.`action_operator` WHEN 'to_percent' THEN cppt.price * cppt.action_amount/100 WHEN 'by_percent' THEN cppt.price * (1 - cppt.action_amount/100) WHEN 'to_fixed' THEN IF((cppt.action_amount < cppt.price), cppt.action_amount, cppt.price) WHEN 'by_fixed' THEN IF((0 > cppt.price - cppt.action_amount), 0, cppt.price - cppt.action_amount) END WHEN IFNULL((@group_id), 'N/A') = cppt.grouped_id AND IFNULL((@action_stop), 0) = 0 THEN @price := CASE `cppt`.`action_operator` WHEN 'to_percent' THEN @price * cppt.action_amount/100 WHEN 'by_percent' THEN @price * (1 - cppt.action_amount/100) WHEN 'to_fixed' THEN IF((cppt.action_amount < @price), cppt.action_amount, @price) WHEN 'by_fixed' THEN IF((0 > @price - cppt.action_amount), 0, @price - cppt.action_amount) END ELSE @price := @price END AS `rule_price`, `cppt`.`from_date` AS `latest_start_date`, `cppt`.`to_date` AS `earliest_end_date`, CASE WHEN IFNULL((@group_id), 'N/A') != cppt.grouped_id THEN @action_stop := cppt.action_stop WHEN IFNULL((@group_id), 'N/A') = cppt.grouped_id THEN @action_stop := IFNULL((@action_stop), 0) + cppt.action_stop END, @group_id := cppt.grouped_id, `cppt`.`from_time`, `cppt`.`to_time` FROM `catalogrule_product_price_tmp` AS `cppt` ORDER BY `cppt`.`grouped_id` ASC, `cppt`.`sort_order` ASC, `cppt`.`rule_product_id` ASC) AS `t` INNER JOIN (SELECT DATE_ADD(FROM_UNIXTIME(1494181800), INTERVAL -1 DAY) AS rule_date UNION SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(1494181800) AS rule_date UNION SELECT DATE_ADD(FROM_UNIXTIME(1494181800), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS rule_date) AS `dates` ON 1=1 WHERE (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(dates.rule_date) >= from_time) AND (IF((to_time = 0), 1, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(dates.rule_date) <= to_time)) GROUP BY `customer_group_id`, `product_id`, `dates`.`rule_date`
```

Comment: I have the same issue.
Have you solved your problem?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/141821)

Answer (score 1):

If the catalogrule_product_price and catalogrule_product tables are empty, it means that the catalog rules have not been applied or generated yet. This can be due to a number of reasons:

1. The Magento cron job is not set up properly or not running at all. Catalog rules are generated and applied by the Magento cron job, so if it's not running, the rules won't be applied. Make sure the cron job is set up correctly and running as expected.
2. The catalog price rule is not set up properly. Double-check your rule settings to make sure everything is configured correctly. Make sure the rule is active, the customer groups are selected, and the conditions are set up correctly.
3. Indexes are not up-to-date. Catalog rules rely on product price index and catalog product price index to apply the rules. If these indexes are not up-to-date, the rules won't be applied. Try re-indexing your Magento store and see if that resolves the issue.
4. Cache is not cleared properly. After updating the rule, you need to flush the cache and re-index the store to make sure the changes are reflected. Make sure you are clearing the cache properly.

Try the following steps:

1. Make sure the Magento cron job is running properly.
2. Double-check your catalog price rule settings to ensure everything is configured correctly.
3. Re-index your Magento store to make sure the product price and catalog product price indexes are up-to-date.
4. Clear your cache and re-index your store.

Answer (score 0):

This works for magento 2, but I think it works also in 1.9

Try...

Insert in `catalogrule`

```
INSERT INTO `catalogrule` (`rule_id`, `name`, `description`, `from_date`, `to_date`, `is_active`, `conditions_serialized`, `actions_serialized`, `stop_rules_processing`, `sort_order`, `simple_action`, `discount_amount`) VALUES (2, '27% from 2 customer group', '', NULL, NULL, 1, '{"type":"Magento\\\\CatalogRule\\\\Model\\\\Rule\\\\Condition\\\\Combine","attribute":null,"operator":null,"value":"1","is_value_processed":null,"aggregator":"all"}', '{"type":"Magento\\\\CatalogRule\\\\Model\\\\Rule\\\\Action\\\\Collection","attribute":null,"operator":"=","value":null}', 0, 0, 'by_percent', 27.0000);
```

in `catalogrule_customer_group`

```
INSERT INTO `catalogrule_customer_group` (`rule_id`, `customer_group_id`) VALUES (2, 1);
INSERT INTO `catalogrule_customer_group` (`rule_id`, `customer_group_id`) VALUES (2, 2);
```

in `catalogrule_group_website`

```
INSERT INTO `catalogrule_group_website` (`rule_id`, `customer_group_id`, `website_id`) VALUES (2, 1, 1);
INSERT INTO `catalogrule_group_website` (`rule_id`, `customer_group_id`, `website_id`) VALUES (2, 2, 1);
```

in `catalogrule_website`

```
INSERT INTO `catalogrule_website` (`rule_id`, `website_id`) VALUES (2, 1);
```

Dont forget to clean cache and reindex.
if it does not work try to enter to the back and in Catalog Rules try to apply rules